# When is parport_driver.attach() called?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am running example "Driver for the Parallel LED Board (led.c)" in the book "Essential Linux Device Drivers". One problem is that led_attach() is never called.

This link http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg38087.html talks the same topic.

"you do first register a class_device with the device name "led" (class_device_create). After that the kernel knows that there is a device called "led". When you register the led_driver, his name is also "led", so the kernel matches the two and call your attach function of your led_driver struct."

I do use "led" as device name and led_driver name, and the module is named led.ko too. However, the led_attach() is not called any way.

Here is my code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>

#include <linux/parport.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

#define DEVICE_NAME "led"

static dev_t dev_number;        /* Allotted device number */
static struct class *led_class; /* Class to which this device belongs */
struct cdev led_cdev;           /* Associated cdev */
struct pardevice *pdev;         /* Parallel port device */

/* LED open */
int led_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "(pid:%d, cmd:%s)led_open(major: %d, minor: %d)\n",
           current->pid, current->comm, imajor(inode), iminor(inode));
    return 0;
}

/* Write to the LED */
ssize_t led_write(struct file *file, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "(pid:%d, cmd:%s)led_write(count: %d, *ppos: %lld)\n",
           current->pid, current->comm, count, *ppos);
    return count;
}

/* Release the device */
int led_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "(pid:%d, cmd:%s)led_release()\n", current->pid, current->comm);
    return 0;
}

/* File Operations */
static struct file_operations led_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = led_open,
    .write = led_write,
    .release = led_release,
};

static int led_preempt(void *handle)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "(pid:%d, cmd:%s)led_preempt()\n", current->pid, current->comm);
    return 1;
}

/* Parport attach method */
static void led_attach(struct parport *port)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "(pid:%d, cmd:%s)led_attach()\n", current->pid, current->comm);

    /* Register the parallel LED device with parport */
    pdev = parport_register_device(port, DEVICE_NAME,
                                   led_preempt, NULL,
                                   NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (pdev == NULL) printk("Bad register\n");
}

/* Parport detach method */
static void led_detach(struct parport *port)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "(pid:%d, cmd:%s)led_detach() Port Detached\n", current->pid, current->comm);
    /* Do nothing */
    parport_unregister_device(pdev);
}

/* Parport driver operations */
static struct parport_driver led_driver = {
    .name = DEVICE_NAME,
    .attach = led_attach,
    .detach = led_detach,
};


/* Driver Initialization */
int __init led_init(void)
{
    printk("led_init()\n");

    /* Request dynamic allocation of a device major number */
    if (alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_number, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME) < 0) {
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "Can't register device\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create the led class */
    led_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(led_class)) printk("Bad class create\n");

    /* Connect the file operations with the cdev */
    cdev_init(&led_cdev, &led_fops);
    led_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;

    /* Connect the major/minor number to the cdev */
    if (cdev_add(&led_cdev, dev_number, 1)) {
        printk("Bad cdev add\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //class_device_create(led_class, NULL, dev_number,
    device_create(led_class, NULL, dev_number, NULL, DEVICE_NAME);

    /* Register this driver with parport */
    // int parport_register_driver (struct parport_driver * drv);
    if (parport_register_driver(&led_driver)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Bad Parport Register\n");
        return -EIO;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Driver Exit */
void __exit led_cleanup(void)
{
    printk("led_cleanup()\n");

    //void parport_unregister_driver (struct parport_driver * arg);
    parport_unregister_driver(&led_driver);
    //class_device_destroy(led_class, MKDEV(MAJOR(dev_number), 0));
    device_destroy(led_class, dev_number);
    cdev_del(&led_cdev);
    class_destroy(led_class);
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev_number, 1);

    return;
}

module_init(led_init);
module_exit(led_cleanup);
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
```

Comment: Hey Hey, saw you on MITBBS. I don't have enough background knowledge either. BUt, have you check dmesg see if your parport driver is loaded correctly by typing: "dmesg | grep par"

Comment: dmesg does not show any error message.

Comment: Nothing from dmesg | grep parp  lots of apparmor from dmesg | grep par. also these 
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.116221] no APIC, boot with the "lapic" boot parameter to force-enable it.
[    0.143191] regulator-dummy: no parameters#
[    2.789935] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered

Comment: Perhaps your parport driver was not loaded correctly or did not find your parallel port? Mine (although it is only a Oracle Virtual Box) shows: [    11.650968] partport pc 00:04: reported by Plug and Play ACPI

Comment: I have disabled loading parport_pc.ko and parport.ko at boot time. And manually load parport.ko before loading led.ko. Your message is generated by parport_pc.ko. However, I tried to load parport_pc.ko too, and then insmod led.ko. This time led_attach() is called!!! I thought led.ko should be enough because there is no error or dependent error message without parport_pc.ko. Any way, it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now we know the answer based on your replies:

Your LED driver depends on parport.ko to interface your driver to generic parallel port. And parport.ko depends on parport_pc.ko to actually detect/attach a "PC styled parallel port". Since you disabled parport_pc, the parallel port will not be detected, and attach event will not be passed to you.

Comment: I go a little further. This time, I change every DEVICE_NAME in the code to "led1", "led2" ... "led5". The purpose is to confirm what is said in this link http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg38087.html. I am surprised the led_attach() is called too. This does not match what the link says. The parport_pc.ko is a real magic.

Comment: One more question associated to this topic is how the driver knows the new data is available on the port. There is no interrupt here. That is why I don't mark this reply as an answer yet.